# Recursive regex pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I know it's going to be a VERY obvious answer, but I can't find anything on how to do this.

I'm trying to unescape `<` and `>` within an HTML string

My test output string is essentially:

````
```php
&gt;h2&lt;Heading2&gt;/h2&lt;
```

`&gt;h2&lt;Heading2&gt;/h2&lt;`

&gt;h2&lt;Heading2&gt;/h2&lt;
````

So in this example we have Github flavoured Markdown, a regular `code` markdown snippet, and then raw text all with the same HTML tag. I want to unescape the raw tag (the third one) to actually become a link. The ideal output would be something like this.

````
```php
&gt;h2&lt;Heading2&gt;/h2&lt;
```

`&gt;h2&lt;Heading2&gt;/h2&lt;`

<h2>Heading2</h2>
````

I'm getting stuck at getting multiple `&gt;` in the same line.

Current regex:

```
/(?:.*?(&gt;))/
```

This will get the first entry.

```
/(?:.*?(&gt;))/g
```

This one gets the second entry. I want it to be able to get EVERY entry. Then, it's just a matter of throwing the tick pieces.

````
/(?:```|`)(?:.*?(&gt;)).*?(?:```|`)/gs
````

Comment: I can only replace the `&gt;` that are NOT within `\`\`\`{here}\`\`\`` and `\`{here}\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're intending on using a regular expression for this task, you can consider the following:

```
var r = s.replace(/((`(?:``)?)[^`]*\2)|&gt;/g, '$1<')
         .replace(/((`(?:``)?)[^`]*\2)|&lt;/g, '$1>')
         .replace(/`[<>]+/g, '`');
```

**[Working Demo](https://eval.in/279658)**

Comment: Thanks hwnd! May I ask why the second replace is necessary? I see the issue, but I'm wondering if we can get it to not add the < after the trailing tick.

Comment: Either way, this will solve it I think, and just run a second with `&lt;` replaced by `$1>`

Comment: Thanks so much! I may end up switching to using AJAX and using my PHP parser, as it's much more complete, but this will work great for now, thanks!